# Libcurl does not update cookie

Tags: c++, cookies, libcurl

I have a test script which sets a test cookie and makes a redirect.
I use cURL v7.33 to test it. 
I enable cookies using:

```
curl_easy_setopt (m_curl, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, "");
```

Then I add cookies using one of methods (tried both):

```
curl_easy_setopt (m_curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, slist);
```

or

```
curl_easy_setopt(m_curl, CURLOPT_COOKIE, "test_cookie_2=base_value2;");
```

Script sets the cookie with the same name but a different value:

```
Set-Cookie: test_cookie_2=value2
```

After redirect cURL sends these cookies to the new URL:

```
Cookie: test_cookie_2=value2; test_cookie_2=base_value2;
```

It's a bug according to RFC 6265 (section 5.3, par.11). Am I right?

I've checked changelog and did not found any notices about this problem.

I use Visual C++ 2013.

[image]

Comment: I've just tried the latest version (7.42.1) - behaves the same way.

Comment: This is simply incorrect use of the libcurl API, as discussed on the curl-library mailing list.

Answer (score 0):

**CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER** option just adds headers "as is" without any parsing and modifying the internal cookie storage in case there cookies were specified.

**CURLOPT_COOKIE** option is just a shortcut for doing the same thing.

**CURLOPT_COOKIELIST** should be used instead. [See the example here](http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/CURLOPT_COOKIELIST.html).